# Square Thumbnail Function with GD Library

Tags: php

I've got this code within a function that generates the thumbnail fine.

My problem is I can't seem to work out how to make the thumbnail square (250x250).

My code is:

```
function make_thumb($img_name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h)
{
$ext=getExtension($img_name);

if(!strcmp("jpg",$ext) || !strcmp("jpeg",$ext))
$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);

if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
$src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);

$old_w = imagesx($src_img);
$old_h = imagesy($src_img);

$original_aspect = $old_w / $old_h;
$thumb_aspect = $new_w / $new_h;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   $thumb_h = $new_h;
   $thumb_w = $old_w / ($old_h / $new_h);
}
else
{
   $thumb_w = $new_w;
   $thumb_h = $old_h / ($old_w / $new_w);
}

$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_w, $thumb_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_w,$old_h);

if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
   imagepng($dst_img,$filename);
else
   imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename);

imagedestroy($dst_img);
imagedestroy($src_img);
}
```

I just can't seem to get my head around how to crop the square image while keeping the image centered/resized.

Does anyone have an idea or could point me in the right direction? I've looked all over S/O and Google :/

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [IMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead? It's much easier to use the GD in my opinion.

Comment: How so? I'm not completely tied to GD

Comment: First of all, Imagick has an easy-to-use [cropThumbnailImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php) function that seems to do exactly what you're asking for. Second of all, Imagick can do anything, and makes it a lot easier for you than GD.

Comment: Okay - Been told I can't use Imagick so GD it is! :/